# Fit the hashmap keys into a method parameters

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm working with an APIs and I'm dealing with a curious problem. A method which comes from an interface has a HashMap as parameter. The keys match with the name of parameter's name of the next method. But we can't ensure that always all keys correspond with the parameters. So, how can I transform hashmap values into parameters in the right way?

Example:

```
import org.api.APIClass;
import org.api.Client;

public class A implements APIClass {
    public void method(Map<String, String> params) {
        /* Example values:
        params {
           key0: value0,
           key1: value1
        }
        */
        // How you could fit the key with corresponding parameters?
        Client.send(String key2, String key1, String key0);        
    } 
}
```

Comment: In the normal way you'd get values out of a HashMap.

Comment: If you know the keys the save them to variables and pass the variables? Maybe I'm misreading this but your problem is pretty straight forward. You'd do it the same way you do for normal methods...?

Comment: The keys in the hash map not are always the same than the paramaters

Comment: Then how are you supposed to guarantee anything without some kind of standardization?

Comment: Think the hashmap as an UI where you pick the keys you want.

Comment: So pick some standardization. You think code can just automagically figure this out at runtime based on an unlimited amount of keys?

Comment: **How** do you pick the keys you want?  We can help with implementation, but not in defining the business logic in the first place.

Comment: The problem is that I cant' change: public void method(Map<String, String> params) because it is an API method that I must implement. And Client.send is also a method from API and I can't change it neither. (API is external not depends of me)

Comment: Well you have an unsolvable problem. How can you order something you know nothing about which is not standardized in any way shape or form

Comment: Maybe something related to reflecion for performing this transformation?

Comment: How will reflection solve your key problem? You don't need reflection to access your hashmap

Comment: Why do **have** to implement method(Map<String, String> params)? What efforts were made to enforce such interface at firsthand?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i fully understand your problem, anyway, here is the way to call a method by reflection if the arguments are stored as values in a Map.

```
class BridgeFactory {
  public static <T> BiConsumer<T, Map<String, ?>> bridge(
      Class<T> declaringClass, String name, String... parameters) {
    Method method;
    try {
      method = declaringClass.getMethod(name,
        Stream.generate(() -> String.class)
              .limit(parameters.length)
              .toArray(Class<?>[]::new));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      throw (Error)new NoSuchMethodError().initCause(e);
    }
    return (obj, map) -> {
      try {
        method.invoke(obj,
             Arrays.stream(parameters).map(map::get).toArray());
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw (Error)new IllegalAccessError().initCause(e);
      } catch(InvocationTargetException e) {
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
          throw (RuntimeException)cause;
        }
        if (cause instanceof Error) {
          throw (Error)cause;
        }
        throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(cause);
      }
    };
  }
}

public class A implements APIClass {
  private static final BiConsumer<Client, Map<String, ?>> SEND =
    BridgeFactory.bridge(Client.class, "send", "key2", "key1", "key0");

  public void method(Map<String, String> params) {      
    SEND.accept(null, params);  // null because the method is static !
  }         
}
```